# NJo es una aplicacion win32 valida programas en c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dev-c++, codeblocks

He estado trabajando en un programa de c++ en DevC++. Todo está funcionando bien hasta que de un momento a otro me sale el error "no es una aplicacion win32 valida". Probe con otros programas que tenía y me daba el mismo error. Pensé que era el IDE, así que probé con CodeBlocks y con Visual Studio pero me sigue saliendo el mismo problema. Lo último que hice fue probarlo en un compilador en el navegador y funcionó perfecto.

No sé que pasa porque antes sí servía. Ayuda!

Comment: Y si compilas manualmente desde la terminal que pasa? Si tienes visual studio busca el path de `cl.exe`, compila, y cuentanos que pasa. Con code blocks creo que es lo mismo pero usando `g++.exe`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.